# Escaping html element in PHP string to prevent invalid output to browser?

Tags: php, html, escaping

I am having problems echoing a string which contains a HTML select element with javascript inside

**Input at Server**

```
 echo '<select name="services" onchange="document.getElementById("services").style.display = this.options.selectedIndex ? "block" : "none";" >';
```

**Output in Browser**

```
<select "none";"="" :="" "block"="" ?="" services").style.display="this.options.selectedIndex" onchange="document.getElementById(" name="services"></select>
```

I have tried escaping the strings using \ character but nothing seems to work.

```
echo '<select name="services" onchange="document.getElementById(\"services\").style.display = this.options.selectedIndex ? \"block\" : \"none\";" >';
```

**Outputs**

```
<select \"none\";"="" :="" \"block\"="" ?="" services\").style.display="this.options.selectedIndex" onchange="document.getElementById(\" name="services"></select>
```

Any tricks or hacks to work around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I highly suggest you learn more about HTML and which characters are allowed in an attribute value. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: @hakre - valid input inside string - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp - inb4 w3fools bandwagon

Comment: The **input** is invalid (before it gets to the PHP string). Trying to fix it up is possible (ish) but you should fix the problem at source. The attributes allowed on a select tag are irrelevant (so you've linked to an irrelevant piece of rubbish, which is doubly bad), the problem is the `"` characters in the values, which is a general HTML attribute rule.

Comment: @Quentin ; nope the problem is because I have used both string encasers " and ' . Nothing wrong with the html and as you can see below jo08691 answer solved my problem!

Comment: @loosebruce — What do you mean "Nope", that's what I said.

Comment: @Quentin you said my html code was wrong which it is not, infact just to please you I will go w3c validate it if youd like

Comment: The validator says: *Validation Output: 13 Errors. No space between attributes. Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.* etc. etc. etc.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CkkAF.png - orly?

Comment: That isn't the HTML you have in your question. You've replaced the `"` that were causing the error with `'`.

Comment: Yes because PHP wouldnt accept the other way of encasing the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 echo "<select name=\"services\" onchange=\"document.getElementById('services').style.display = this.options.selectedIndex ? 'block' : 'none';\" >";
```

Comment: @ehudokai ; calm down! go have a herbal tea!

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '<select name="services" onchange="document.getElementById(\"services\").style.display = this.options.selectedIndex ? \"block\" : \"none\";" >';
```